# Create dynamic components from collection

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create components from a collection:

```
    var sections = [
       {name: 'EditStudentBasicDetails',key: 1, title: 'Basic Details', sectionData: this.state.studentData.activeData.basicDetails},
        {name: 'EditStudentAgentsInfo', key: 2, label: 'Agents Info', sectionData: this.state.studentData.activeData.agentsInfo },
```

Can I create the following components by mapping the above collection?

```
    <Tabs activeKey={this.state.activeTabId} onSelect={this.handleSelect} bsStyle="tabs">
         <Tab eventKey={1} title="Basic Details"  >
              <EditDetails studentId={this.state.studentId} sectionData={this.state.studentData.activeData.basicDetails} />
        </Tab>
        <Tab eventKey={2} title="Agents Info">
            <EditMoreDetails studentId={this.state.studentId} sectionData={this.state.studentData.activeData.agentsInfo} />
        </Tab>
```

How would I create the component 'EditMoreDetails' for example using the `map?

Something like this?

```
{this.sections.map(function(section) {
                    return  <Tab key={key} title={title}  >
                                <{name} sectionData={this.state.studentData.activeData.basicDetails} />
                            </Tab>;
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing `<EditDetails/>` you are in fact calling `React.createElement(EditDetails)`, `EditDetails` is not a string, but a `ReactClass` function.

You can add on your sections object the `ReactClass` instead of its string name:

```
const sections = [{Component: EditDetails}, ...]
```

And then when mapping the data to components do:

```
sections.map(section => <section.Component/>)
```

If you don't want to add the components inside of your data, you can create a hash table to map the strings to the components:

```
const componentTable = {
  EditDetails: EditDetails,
}
```

And then do:

```
sections.map(section => {
  const Component = componentTable[section.name]
  return <Component/>  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

React doesn't support this level of "interpolation" or "registry" which is why you won't be able to render a component based on a string.

You can do the normal `window[name]` dance but that's normally not recommended.

I would guess that a simple `switch` would suffice for your use case.

```
{this.sections.map(function(section) {
    return <Tab key={key} title={title}  >
        switch(name) {
        case "EditDetails":
            return <EditDetails sectionData={this.state.studentData.activeData.basicDetails} />;
        }
    </Tab>;
})}
```

[A bit of good reading where rendering components from strings are discussed.](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3365)